# Journey Builder Sends folder not visible in Email Studio > Tracking Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-tracking

As the title suggests, I have multiple business units and it appears none of my child BU's have the "Journey Builder Sends" folder under Email Studio > Tracking > Sends.

Does this need to be provisioned by SF?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue and found the solution here:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000334113&type=1

> Resolution
>
> The below solution should regenerate the folders through
> the logic in place after hitting Save.
>
> 1. Navigate to the Business Unit that is missing the Journey Builder Sends Folder.
> 2. Navigate to Journey Builder
> 3. Click “Create New Journey”
> 4. Select a “Single Send Journey” (Which option you pick doesn’t matter)
> 5. Click “Save”
>
> The Journey Builder Sends folder should now be visible in the Interactions tab and Tracking tab in the Email Studio application.
>
> NOTE: If it doesn’t show up immediately sign out then sign back in.

Answer (score 0):

Just finding this question. If the issue is a permissions issue, then the permission you need to allow is in: `Transactional Sending > Messages > Tracking`. This is outside of the 'Email' permission in setup.

[image: marketing cloud tracking permission for journey builder]